# Plug-in handled load UIWebview

Tags: plugins, uiwebview, mp4

I am developing an iPad application that plays videos from Internet Video Archive (IVA).
I can play the IVA URL in iPad-Safari. But, I am able to get it streamed in my app.
I am doing the following things to play the video:

1. Add an outlet to webview in the nib.
2. I have written the following code in my play method:

   `NSString *myURl = //Internet Video Archive URL; the video is in mp4 format
   CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
   webview.frame = webFrame;
   [webview setDelegate: self];
   [webview loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: myURl]]];`
3. It gives the following error:

> Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=204 UserInfo=0x1b2e30 "Plug-in
>   handled load"

I could play videos from other sites. Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Deepa

Comment: When using UIWebView, the issue also occurs with M4A (MPEG-4 Audio) and M4V (MPEG-4 Video) files. In my case, all files are local and M4A actually plays, but no "player control" is displayed. Since I receive an error in via `webView:didFailLoadWithError:`, I cancel the modal dialog. For M4V, the video does not play and an error is received in `webView:didFailLoadWithError:`. I also cancel the modal view.